# Notepad++ Making FunctionList work with .js

Tags: notepad++

I have installed Notepad++ on Win7, versions 7.3.3 and 7.4.2, with both versions i open a javascript file, navitage to View>FunctionList

Function list appears blank.

I found another Function list on sourcefourge, plugin version 2.1 which works a bit, however, i have to update the language rules and press "try!" button for every JS code file, and then the functions appear.

Please, does someone know how to install Notepad++ and have FunctionList working for .js?

I didn't use AppData, I installed all notepad++ files to the notepad++ directory.

Answer (score 6):

You want this *<parser>* for javascript. It is in file *functionlist.xml*, either in the install directory of NPP, or somewhere in AppData, which you want to modify. This does not handle all cases (of comments in function headers), but most cases.

In addition, the *langID* number of javascript is *19*, not *58*. Your issue looks like *langID*, but after that fixed, you will detect that you need the adapted <parser>.

association ids are here, and do have to be both in the file *functionlist.xml*:

```
<association id=  "javascript_function"   langID="58"                          />
<association id=  "javascript_function"   langID="19"                          />
```

parser is here, adaptation-me:

```
<parser
    displayName="JavaScript"
    id         ="javascript_function"
    XcommentExpr="(?s:/\*.*?\*/)|(?m-s://.*?$)"


    bemerkung1="für Kommentar zwischen function header und {. [\n\s]*\{ am Ende gelöscht."
    bemerkung2="für new Function(...)  (?:new\s*)? eingefügt."
    bemerkung3="für function (a,b,c) ohne Funktionsname ein \s* eingefügt."
    bemerkung4="Kommentar im Funktionsheader wird nicht behandelt, z.B. function /*returns real*/ a(b) { } "
    bemerkung5="commentExpr überhaupt X-ed."
    bemerkung99="Es muss etwas falsch sein mit commentExpr durch nichts ersetzen."

    comment1="Comment between function header and function body {: removed [\n\s]*\{ "
    comment2="new Function(): inserted (?:new\s*)? "
    comment3="function (a,b,c) without function name: inserted \s*" 
    comment4="Comment within function header still not handled. e.g. function /*returns real*/ a(b) { } "
    comment5="commentExpr disabled: X-ed."
    comment99="There must be something wrong with replacing commentExpr by nothing."

>
<function
    mainExpr="((^|\s+|[;\}\.])([A-Za-z_]\w*\.)*[A-Za-z_]\w*\s*[=:]|^|[\s;\}]+)\s*(?:new\s*)?function(\s+[A-Za-z_]?\w*\s*\([^\)\(]*\)|s*\([^\)\(]*\))"
>
    <functionName>
        <nameExpr expr="[A-Za-z_]\w*\s*[=:]|[A-Za-z_]?\w*\s*\(" />
        <nameExpr expr="[A-Za-z_]?\w*" />
    </functionName>
    <className>
        <nameExpr expr="([A-Za-z_]\w*\.)*[A-Za-z_]\w*\." />
        <nameExpr expr="([A-Za-z_]\w*\.)*[A-Za-z_]\w*" />
    </className>
</function>
</parser>
```

Comment: did you mean functionlist.xml rather than filelist.xml?

Comment: to LeasMaps: I fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Finaly!! I managed to make function list working with both "prototype" syntax and ECMAScript 6 "class" syntax for object declaration. For that, I used [this thread for prototype syntax](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/8647/configure-function-list-to-show-javascript-class-functions-created-with-prototype)
and [typescript detection for EC6 class Syntax](https://github.com/chai2010/notepadplus-typescript/blob/master/functionList.xml)

The result is there :

```
<parser
    displayName="JavaScript"
    id         ="javascript_function"
    commentExpr="(?s:/\*.*?\*/)|(?m-s://.*?$)"
>


    <!-- <classRange>, ES6 "class" Syntax inspired of typescript : https://github.com/chai2010/notepadplus-typescript/blob/master/functionList.xml   -->
    <classRange
        mainExpr="^\s*(export\s+)?(class|interface)\s+\w+\s*((extends|implements)\s+(\w|\s|,|\.|[^{])*)?\{"
        openSymbole = "\{"
        closeSymbole = "\}"
        displayMode="node">
        <className>
            <nameExpr expr="(export\s+)?(class|interface)\s+\w+"/>
            <nameExpr expr="(class|interface)\s+\w+"/>
            <nameExpr expr="\s+\w+"/>
            <nameExpr expr="\w+"/>
        </className>
        <!-- Indent only support tab/2space/4space!!! -->
        <!-- tab/2space is best choice!  -->
        <!-- regexp: ^(\t|[ ]{2,4})  -->
        <function
            mainExpr="(^(\t|[ ]{2,4})((static)\s+)+\w+\s*(\(|\=|:|\?))|(^(\t|[ ]{2,4})\w+\s*(\(|:|\=|\?))">
            <functionName>
                <funcNameExpr expr="(^(\t|[ ]{2,4})((static)\s+)+\w+\s*(\(|\=|:|\?))|(\w+\s*(\(|:|\=|\?))"/>
                <funcNameExpr expr="(\s+\w+\s*(\(|\=|:|\?))|(\w+\s*(\(|:|\=|\?))"/>
                <funcNameExpr expr="(\s+\w+\s*(\(|\=|:|\?))|(\w+)"/>
                <funcNameExpr expr="(\s+\w+)|(\w+)"/>
                <funcNameExpr expr="\w+"/>
            </functionName>
        </function>
    </classRange>


    <!-- <classRange>, "prototype" syntax imported from :https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/8647/configure-function-list-to-show-javascript-class-functions-created-with-prototype -->
    <classRange 
        mainExpr="^[\t ]*([_A-Za-z]?[\w_]*)(\.prototype)+[\s]+(=)+[\s]*\{" openSymbole = "\{" closeSymbole = "\}" displayMode="node"
    >
        <className>
            <nameExpr expr="[_A-Za-z]+[\w_]*"/>
        </className>
        <function mainExpr="^[\t ]*([_A-Za-z]?[\w_])+[\s]*+:+[\s]*+function+[\s]*\("> 
            <functionName>
                <funcNameExpr expr="^[\t ]*([_A-Za-z]?[\w_]*)"/>
            </functionName>
            </function>
    </classRange>


    <!-- Orgiginal notepad++ functionlist -->
    <function
        mainExpr="((^|\s+|[;\}\.])([A-Za-z_$][\w$]*\.)*[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*\s*[=:]|^|[\s;\}]+)\s*function(\s+[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*)?\s*\([^\)\(]*\)[\n\s]*\{"
    >
        <functionName>
            <nameExpr expr="[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*\s*[=:]|[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*\s*\(" />
            <nameExpr expr="[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*" />
        </functionName>
        <className>
            <nameExpr expr="([A-Za-z_$][\w$]*\.)*[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*\." />
            <nameExpr expr="([A-Za-z_$][\w$]*\.)*[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*" />
        </className>
    </function>

</parser>
```

Tested with notepad++ v7.8.1 
Function list to edit is here : C:\Users[YourSessionUser]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\functionList.xml

Comment: I had to update C:\Users\YourSessionUser\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\functionList\javascript.js.xml for V8.1.4

Answer (score 1):

In version 7.5.7 I followed the steps outlined in Peter's answer above but edited functionList.xml in the directory where notepad++ is installed (for me C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++) and deleted the old functionList.xml in %APPDATA%\Notepad++ (see also https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/4697)

Answer (score 0):

I did not have success with top answer in Notepad 7.6.6 so made the alternative below.

I want to capture functions inside a `class` (introduced in ECMAScript 2015; see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)) and therefore it can't rely on a `function` keyword to trigger a match.

The parser I present below is a nasty hack that does not work in all situations and produces occasional false matches. However it is getting the job done for me, and I couldn't find anything better elsewhere online... I hope it helps someone :)

```
    <parser
        displayName="JavaScript"
        id         ="javascript_function"
        commentExpr="(?s:/\*.*?\*/)|(?m-s://.*?$)"
    >
        <function
            mainExpr="((^|\s+|[;\}\.])([A-Za-z_$][\w$]*\.)*[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*\s*[=:]|^|[\s;\}]+)\s*((function)|[$\t]*)(?(?![\s]*(for|if|while))(\s+[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*)?|(failtomatch))\s*\([^\)\(]*\)[\n\s]*\{"
        >
            <functionName>
                <nameExpr expr="[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*\s*[=:]|[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*\s*\(" />
                <nameExpr expr="[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*" />
            </functionName>
            <className>
                <nameExpr expr="([A-Za-z_$][\w$]*\.)*[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*\." />
                <nameExpr expr="([A-Za-z_$][\w$]*\.)*[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*" />
            </className>
        </function>
    </parser>
```

The changes I made the the `mainExpr` regular expression have the following effect

- `(function)|[$\t]*)` instead of just checking that the keyword `function` appears before a function name, also allow for zero or more end-lines or tabs to signal the start of a function.
- `(?(?![\s]*(for|if|while))(\s+[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*)?|(failtomatch))` Then, as long as the characters which appear before the `(...arguments)` are not `for`, `if` or `while`, we can assume that this is a function name. Otherwise cause the entire match to fail by trying to match the string `"failtomatch"` (which hopefully isn't the actual name of your function) (also if your function name starts with `for`, `if` or `while` it will also be discarded.)
- Hopefully posting this will get someone to help solve this a bit better - I did my best with my limited knowledge of regex :P

Comment: Hello, I tryed on an other computer with an older notepad++ and my solution didn't work. I had to uptate to the last version (7.8.2). Can you try with a newer version please?
I've also noticed that your scrpit must finish by an new line to make my solution work. if it finised with '}' you have to add a new line. let me know if it works. thx